# Load parent and children dynamically in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to figure out how to load data dynamically in react.

I made a example where I am loading all the parents as div.cards. Each parent do have a checkbox. Whenever you press a checkbox, you should get the chosen parents children.

The problem I am facing right now:

- Whenever I press a checkbox, I load all childrens to **all** parents. I just want to load the children to the chosen parent(clicked checkbox div).
- Since I am loading the data dynamically, all checkboxes seems to get the same ID, any suggestions on how to fix this aswell?
- Can I somehow also destroy the div of the children if I uncheck the checkbox?

I made a example here: 
https://jscomplete.com/playground/s504328

Help is appreciated, and if you see something I could Improve, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rendering childData based on `this.state.childData` which will be referenced by both the parents.

I suggest you change the structure to something like

```
 this.state = {
            parentData: [{
              "title": "ParentTitle",
              "id": 1,
              "childData": [{
                 "title": "child1",
                 "id": 1
              }]
            }],
            loading: true,
            id: '',
        };
```

I have created a fiddle with the solution you require.
https://jsfiddle.net/8w0o5a2m/1/
I have removed the async functions from code for simplicity

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am still having problem with this solution. If I understand you correctly, you are saying that I should render the parent aswell each time I am getting the children? How am I supposed to render the child in this example? this.state.parentData.childData? Or Am I missing your point?

Comment: @arkhz I have edited the answer with a link to a fiddle with the expected behavior

Comment: I understand it better now, thanks alot for the help!